# VBA in Outlook to pull specific data into excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

I need some VBA code in outlook to save specific lines of data from emails as per below into an excel folder - see sample excel table below.  I need the code to search all emails in my personal inbox only and save into the excel file in a specific location. Any ideas?

**EMAIL:**

```txt
From: Matt.Brown@hotmail.com
to: Lucy.Brown@hotmail.com

Subject: Client Orders
Product: Trunk1
Units: 463
```

Thanks

**Excel file saved in a specific location:**

```txt
Client Sales    Product       Units
xx                   xx        xx
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Restrict` or `Find`/`FindNext` methods of the `Items` class to find items in the folder that correspond to your conditions/search criteria. If you need to search for items in multiple folders you may consider using the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
- [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/)

For example, the following code searches for items from a specified sender and then calls a method to export the data from an item found to an Excel workbook:

```
Sub ExportItemsFromSender() 
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim myItems As Outlook.Items 
 Dim myItem As Object 
 
 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
 Set myItems = myInbox.Items 
 
 Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = 'Eugene Astafiev'") 
 
 While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing" 
   ExportItemToExcelWorkbook myItem 
   Set myItem = myItems.FindNext 
 Wend 
End Sub
```

The [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-visual-basic) article explains how to automate Excel from another application (Outlook VBA in your case).

Comment: Hi, thank you - it falls over on:

ExportItemToExcelWorkbook myItem.

Where do I define the folder where my excel table is saved?

Comment: You need to define the function in the code according to your needs.